# Distance between a point and a set 5

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be a **closed** subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, $k\geq2$, with **empty interior**, and $B_{n}$ the set of the points having a distance equal to $1/n$ from $A$, and $n=1,2,...$. Can we say that for all $a$ in $ A$ there is a sequence $(b_{n})$ in $B_{n}$ that converges to $a$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: No. Take for example, the union of circles with radius 1/n to gather with 0. But if we disregard cases like this, what is the answer???

Comment: Why do you want to disregard such cases? What is the purpose of the question?

Comment: You are right, let's not disregard this. Then what is the necessary and sufficient condition(s) that the problem have a solution?